# PowerShell nested variables, treating values as variables

Tags: powershell, azure

Below I have my script which works while connected to Azure via PowerShell (so you can test if you have an Azure account), at the top is gathers a list of Azure storage accounts listing a choice, while at the same time creating a variable ($A, $B, $C, $D etc) for each storage account it finds. Below in the answer section my variable $StorageSelection resolves to one of them, e.g. $B, however as $B is also a variable, rather than running $B directly I want to be able to run $StorageSelection which has the value of $B and I want to treat the value of $B like a variable which display $B's value. Its like converting the value of $StorageSelection to a variable and running it at the same time. Sorry if this sounds confusing, but it's been doing my head in for hours stuck on this very bit.

```
do {
    $AzureStorageAccount = Get-AzureStorageAccount
    $StorageCount = ($AzureStorageAccount | Measure).Count
    write-host ""
    write-host "Choose a storage account"
    write-host ""

    $StorageNumber = 0
    do {
    $StepAzureStorageAccount = $AzureStorageAccount | select -Skip $StorageNumber | select -First 
    $GatherStorageAccountName = ($StepAzureStorageAccount).StorageAccountName
    $GatherLocation = @(if (($StepAzureStorageAccount).Location -ne $null) {($StepAzureStorageAccount).Location} `
    else {($StepAzureStorageAccount).AffinityGroup})
    $StorageLetter = $([char](65 + $StorageNumber))
    New-Variable -Name "${StorageLetter}" -Value $StepAzureStorageAccount -Force
    write-host $StorageLetter" - "$GatherStorageAccountName", "$GatherLocation
    $StorageNumber++
       }
    while ($StorageNumber -lt $StorageCount)

    write-host ""
    write-host "X - Exit"
    write-host ""
    write-host -nonewline "Type your choice and press Enter: "

    $choice = read-host

    write-host ""

    $ok = $choice -like '*'

    if ( -not $ok) { write-host "Invalid selection" }
} until ( $ok )

New-Variable -Name "${choice}" -Value $StorageSelection -Force
$storage = $StorageSelection
write-host "You entered"($Storage).StorageAccountName""
```

Comment: Where do you define `$StorageSelection` ? I see you use it, but I don't see where it's created.

Comment: It's defined on the third last line

Comment: The third to last line defines a variable with a name derived from the value of `${choice}` (i.e "B"), then attempts to initialize it with the value of `$StorageSelection`. The result of that will be `$B = $null`

Comment: Yes, but that's not entirely true, the top section would have $B already defined on this line `New-Variable -Name "${StorageLetter}" -Value $StepAzureStorageAccount -Force`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By any chance, is this what you want to do?

```
New-Variable -Name StorageSelection -Value (Get-Variable $choice).value -Force
```

which can also be written:

```
$StorageSelection = (Get-Variable $choice).value
```

Let me explain so you can confirm my line of thought:

You have:

`$StepAzureStorageAccount` containing some Azure account info.

You then build several variables `$A $B $C` etc. depending on the account info.

You then ask the user to select one of these variables (in the form A, B, C) and store the response in `$choice`.

So for example, the value of `$Choice` is `"B"` and you want `$B` which contains to some other data (`$StepAzureStorageAccount`)

You finally want to create a new variable, called `$StorageSelection` which receives the value of what the variable pointed to by `$choice` contains.

If the language was C/C++, I'd say, you have a pointer which points to another pointer, which points to a value. Except this is not C and pointers don't exactly exist.

However `Get-Variable` exists. And what it does, it creates an object of type `PSVariable` which contains the name and value of another variable.

So if `$B = "foo"` and `$choice = "B"` then `$StorageSelection` will contain `"foo"`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your awesome and prompt explanation, been busy today Saturday with the kids. It's evening now so first chance I have had to look at this. But in your example, if `$B = "foo"` and `$choice = "B"` then `$StorageSelection` will contain `"foo"`   in this example, its actually this what is happening on my end `$B = "foo"` and `$choice = "B"` then `$StorageSelection` contains `"$B"`    I need it so `$StorageSelection = "foo"` the same as how `$B = "foo"` (in the first instance)